# how to print a certificate from CA in text form with openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate

I know how to see certificate files in text form with openssl with the following command:

```
$ openssl x509 -in example.crt -text -noout
```

I happened to download a csr file for thawte in the following link: http://tj.symcb.com/tj.crt

And applying the same command to tj.crt results in this error message:

```
$ openssl x509 -in tj.crt -text
unable to load certificate
140736213377928:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:704:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I just want to see who issued the certificate and what not on my own with the command. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

The file that you provided the link to is not 'csr' - 'certificate signing request' but certificate itself.

When you want to get the information from the certificate in text form then your command is correct, you just need to add `-inform DER` since the certificate is in binary form instead of PEM format.